# Prepend prefix in tar

Tags: bash, tar

I currently do in a shellscript very inefficiently:

```
cp -a $MYPATH /tmp/$VERSION
cd /tmp
tar cjf archive.tar.bz2 $VERSION
```

I want everything to be contained in the directory called $VERSION - is there a way to do this without having to copy everything as in the above script?

Comment: Why copying it in the first place? Why not `tar cjf archive.tar.bz2 $MYPATH`?

Comment: @Chewie he said, he want the $version as parent dir in archive.

Comment: Oh, I see it now.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and decided to keep coping files. Inefficiency was not critical. `--transform` gives slightly different archive structure without `$VERSION` itself. That broke unpacking side, that was not under my control.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The GNU version of `tar` supports the `--transform` option (and its alias `--xform`), you could use it like this

```
tar --transform "s/^$MYPATH/$VERSION/" -cf archive.tar.bz2 "$MYPATH"
```

For example, given this directory tree

```
foo
└── foo.txt
```

the command

```
tar --transform "s/^foo/bar/" -cf foo.tar.bz2 foo
```

will produce an archive like

```
$ tar -tf foo.tar.bz2
bar/
bar/foo.txt
```

Comment: It is noteworthy that this approach might break symbolic links. Prepending `flags=r;` solves the problem as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29661783/388803.

Comment: don't include a trailing slash; when I put a trailing slash in the transform, the original prefix is missed; eg `s/^a\//b\//`, the `tar -t` still shows `a/` while all other files are under `b/`; I assume this is hazardous, and I don't really need to protect against some other file with the same prefix that isn't a directory in the tar file; so no trailing slash is fine, I woudln't mind knowing the best way to handle the case of `a/` being transformed but not `aa/` if it were a sibling of the root node.

Answer (score 18):

To tar the current directory and add a prefix, this worked for me:

```
tar --transform 's,^\.,$VERSION,' -cf foo.tar .
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I found I had to use: `tar --transform 's,^,$VERSION/,' -cf foo.tar .`

Answer (score 1):

To add a directory prefix comfortably, use a different separator than `/` in the `--transform` argument, e.g. `+` or `,` like in Andy's answer.

So, for a simpler case, you have a bunch of files in current directory, and you don't want to create a [tarbomb](http://www.linfo.org/tarbomb.html).

```
tar czf logs_nightly.tar.gz --tranform 's+^+logs_nightly/+' *.log
```

The syntax is `s+search+replace+`, and for `^` it simply matches the start of filename.

And now, just to answer the OP - well, you can avoid copying your whole directory to `/tmp` by running:

```
mv $MYPATH $VERSION
tar cjf archive.tar.bz2 $VERSION
mv $VERSION $MYPATH
```

Alternatively:

```
ln $MYPATH $VERSION
tar cjf archive.tar.bz2 $VERSION
```

(hard link, avoids problems with symlinks)

The last two were included for entertainment value, I myself would stick to toro2k's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away without preserving symbolic links within the file tree you're tarring, you could do

```
ln -s $MYPATH /tmp/$VERSION
cd /tmp
tar cjhf archive.tar.bz2 $VERSION
```

The `h` option means dereference symlinks, i.e. include the file or directory that the link points to rather than simply recording the fact that there was a symlink and what it pointed to.